# Kentico Email Widget using custom contact fields

Tags: macros, kentico, email

I'm creating an email template using Kentico's email marketing module. In which I have an email widget that retrieves and fills in holiday detail parameters based on some custom contact field values therefore making this dynamic for each user.

How can I pass custom contact fields in to the widgets from the recipient? The recipient object only contains set values.

Contacts for this email campaign are collected from a form submission that passes in the required values.

```
<div style="display:none;">
    {% holidayDate = Recipient.GetValue("holidayDate"); #%}
    {% holidayId = Recipient.GetValue("holidayId"); %}
    {% ItineraryData = customNamespace.GetItineraryItem(holidayId, holidayDate) #%}
</div>

<h2 class="price">{% ItineraryData.GetValue("Price") #%}</div>
```

Something like the above is what I am trying to achieve but I can't seem to work out how to get these custom fields to use in the email widget.

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/on-line-marketing-features/configuring-and-customizing-your-on-line-marketing-features/configuring-email-marketing/reference-email-marketing-macro-expressions#Reference-Emailmarketingmacroexpressions-Recipient) states `Recipient` only has 4 available fields:

- FirstName
- LastName
- Email
- PersonaID

If you want to get custom fields, you'll have to look up the contact by the email address, first and last name in a macro.

Comment: Thanks for this Brenden. Is it possible to get the field value out of a bizForm this way using a macro. Looking up using the same parameters you mentioned? FirstName, LastName and Email? Do you know of an example of how to achieve this?